# Add fragment to current activity replacing previous layout

Tags: android, android-fragments

In `<FrameLayout>` I'm trying to replace with a fragment but the previous layout is still visible. If I use match_parent, the screen is blank.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/fragment"></FrameLayout>

<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnWidth="200dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What is your _question_? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
_How_ are trying to replace a fragment? (Show some code).
What is "previous layout"? (Show some pictures).

Comment: `FragmentTransaction`s deal only with `Fragment`s. They will not remove/replace `View`s that are not in a `Fragment`. If you want that `GridView` to be replaced, put it in its own `Fragment` that can be transacted out.